# Floating action button hidden by fragment android 4.4

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

My floating action button is in the Main Activity, the fragment tabs hide the floating action button on my android 4.4 device. Works fine on my android 7.0 device. Elevation doesn't seem to work. How will I make it show?

On Android 4.4
[image]

On android 7.0
[image]

My floating action button xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/create_icon"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:fabSize="normal" />
```

Comment: You should post full xml with Viewpager too

Answer (score 0):

Use `app:elevation` instead of `android:elevation` as FloatingActionButton belongs to support library. It should work.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. I could implement a custom style for the floating action button but it's just a lot of work for just one view.